# Can I send simultaneous (instead of sequential) Arduino outputs?

Tags: for-loop, arduino, output

I have eight LEDs that I'm fading in and out with an Arduino. I'm controlling each individually with the following code.

```
  for(int fade1=0;fade1<=255;fade1+=1){
   analogWrite(8,fade1); 
   delay(10);
  }
  for(int fade1=255;fade1>=0;fade1-=1){
    analogWrite(8,fade1);
    delay(10);
  }
```

I want to be able to assign a separate fade time and delay to each of eight separate pins, so all eight lights are fading in and out simultaneously, and loop infinitely. However, I can only get them to kick off sequentially with my program.

I've been playing with different placement of the for loops, loops within loops, etc., but can't seem to make it do what I want. Any ideas or examples to which someone can refer me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having 16 loops, reduce them to two:

```
  for(int fade1=0;fade1<=255;fade1+=1){
   analogWrite(8,fade1);
   analogWrite(9,fade1); 
   // etc.
   delay(10);
  }
  for(int fade1=255;fade1>=0;fade1-=1){
    analogWrite(8,fade1);
    analogWrite(9,fade1);
    // etc.
    delay(10);
  }
```

You won't be able to observe the difference in time from when port 8 is written to when port 9 is written.  This code will cause the LEDs to fade in and out simultaneously, but you might want them to fade individually?

In this case you will need to set the fade value for each LED separately, so define a vector of fade values, with initial values:

```
  int fade[8] = {2, 0, 4,200,20,47,45,150};
  int dir[8]  = {1,-1, 1, -1, 1,-1, 1, -1};

  loop() {
      for (i = 0; i < 8, i++)
      {
         if ((fade[i] <= 0) || (fade[i] >= 255))
         {
            dir[i] *= -1;
         } else
           fade[i] += dir[i];
         }
         // + 8 for leds at ports 8 thru 15
         analogWrite(i+8, fade[i]);
      }
      delay(10);

   }
```

Caution, I haven't tried this code but it is a good start on the LEDs appearing to run independently of each other.

Comment: Excellent! That looks like a great start to begin my experiments, and gives me some ideas for randomizing some of the values as well...

Answer (score 1):

If you need an extensive list of examples you want to have a look at my blog. Especially in the [removing flicker](http://blog.blinkenlight.net/experiments/removing-flicker/) section I have lots of examples on how to fade 20 LEDs independently and with high update frequency.